# I can't post to localhost what I see in the terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to monitor .hprof files in the system using Grafana, so I wrote a small Flask app. I am able to access localhost, I am able to see the number of hprof files on terminal, but I cannot see the number of hprof files on my localhost. Here is my code:

```py
import fnmatch,os
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hprof():
    num_files = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir("/home/ubuntu/files"),'*.hprof'))
    return("Total hprof files: ", num_files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-virtual-machine:~/hprof$ python3 hprof.py
 * Serving Flask app "hprof" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 284-945-814
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2022 11:58:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 3 -
```

What I see on localhost:

```
Total hprof files:
```

Can anyone briefly explain how to solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include code and any tracebacks as text and not as images.  That said,  that isn't how ```print()``` works in relation to Flask.  When you do a ```print()```, it goes to the terminal.  If you want to have it printed on the localhost, you should also return that info with the ```return``` line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ewong, i tried to explain as your said. I deleted the print part and added on the return part but now i can not see num_files data on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I solved it by entering

```
localhost:8000
```

In the browser search bar.

Comment: Hello and welcome too. I tried as both style like `0.0.0.0:8000` and `localhost:8000` but it was same. I can not see the num_files part on localhost

Answer (score 0):

In a view function, returning a tuple like this:

```py
return("Total hprof files: ", num_files)
```

means that Flask treats it as a `(response, status)` tuple, so `num_files` is used for the HTTP status code.

In order to return your intended response, you need to return a single string:

```py
return "Total hprof files: " + str(num_files)
```

See the [relevant Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#about-responses) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem adding  ```return("Total hprof files: {}".format(num_files))``` but it works also your suggestion.